# Solving recurrence $T(n) = 8T(\frac n3) +T(\frac n3 + 1) + n$

Tags: recurrence-relations

> Solving recurrence $T(n) = 8T(\frac n3) +T(\frac n3 + 1) + n$

Is there some general idea when solving recurrences like this? I tried substituting $n\to 3n$ and got:

$T(3n) = 8T(n) + T(n + 1)$ which is a little more approachable but still, I can't use the characteristic polynomial on this, how would I solve it?

Comment: Is there a base case, e.g. $T(1)=1$?

Comment: Yes, you can consider $T(1) = 1$